# Can PODs have implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, struct

Can PODs have implicit conversion, both to and from the POD, and still remain a POD?

```
struct POD
{
   int a;
   
#ifdef __cplusplus
   POD(int _a) : a(_a) {}
   operator int() const { return a; }
#endif
};
```

note that I need `Data` to be POD in c++ as well, I want implicit conversions only as a syntactic sugar. So I need the optimizations that a compiler would do with a POD since this is used in hot path of the program.

Comment: You find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/6752050)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By providing a converting constructor you removed the implicit default constructor and made the struct non POD. Return the default constructor and you get a POD.

```
struct POD
{
   int a;
   
#ifdef __cplusplus
   POD() = default;
   POD(int _a) : a(_a) {}
   operator int() const { return a; }
#endif
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You class is not POD since it does not have a (trivial) default constructor. If you add one and make sure it's trivial, the class becomes POD.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7EcE6bxo8